# Why do I get PERMISSION_DENIED when subscribing to a Firebase Topic

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a call to Firebase to subscribe to a topic, using

https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd

as shown in

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

The only documented errors are

```
NOT_FOUND — The registration token has been deleted or the app has been uninstalled.
INVALID_ARGUMENT — The registration token provided is not valid for the Sender ID.
INTERNAL — The backend server failed for unknown reasons. Retry the request.
TOO_MANY_TOPICS — Excessive number of topics per app instance.
```

This code has worked fine for months and has not been changed.  However for some reason I am now seeing this error returned

PERMISSION_DENIED

Can anyone explain 
a) why I should be getting an error which is not documented and 
b) what does this error actually indicate.

Thanks

```
            // This is the send part of the POST



    string m_FirebaseServerKey  = "<firebase server key for project goes here>";
    string m_url            = "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd";
    m_RegistrationToken         = new string[] { appIID };
            m_Topic             = topic;

    var request = WebRequest.Create(m_url);
            // Add headers from parameters
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "key=" + m_FirebaseServerKey ;

            var RequestData = new
            {
                to = "/topics/" + m_Topic,
                registration_tokens = m_RegistrationToken
            };

            // serialise
            string SerializedRequest = SerializeContent(RequestData);

            // send request
            var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(SerializedRequest);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Could you specify how exactly you called the API?

Comment: code snippet added above.

Comment: If the code is truly completely unchanged, than it's probably a parameter value. Are your tokens/keys up to date, not recycled, etc? Did you change any permissions somewhere using the Firebase console?

Comment: Just curious, but are you using .NET for the code snippet you’ve added?

Comment: Thanks you Edric, Paul for responses.  No permissions changed via the console. I am using .NetCore on Ubuntu.

Comment: Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: I get the same issue for python sdk. does anyone know of solution to this. Thanks